# Auto executable file - Android ADB install

Tags: android, macos, bash, shell, adb

I created this account to ask this question, however I have been searching all over google and this website to find what i'm looking for however i haven't at all.

I come from windows and mac os x is very new to me still, even though i've been working with a mac now for a few months. As the title suggests, I want to create a file that will execute upon double clicking and will execute a list of commands. It seems very basic yes, but i'm having a difficult time getting started.

The purpose of this file will be to run a list of android adb commands and directory changes to install a very long list of android apps to any device that is connected. The file must execute in the same way as if i were typing in the commands myself in bash. Can someone help me with this? Or even provide a guide showing me how?

Comment: this is not a site where you simply list your requirements and expect someone to write the code you need. while your question is indeed very simple it is also very poorly written and it is very unlikely to help anyone else. voting to close

Comment: I do not expect someone to write the code i need. It unlikely to help someone else because no one else is asking for this type of thing. I searched google and this website, and found nothing, because no information exists or is readily available. What would you suggest I do if i cannot be helped here

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting is to create the Mac or Unix equivilant of .bat files.  If you Google, "mac osx terminal shell scripts" this will put you on to the right track.  Also look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-TP40003516-SW1.